# Dynamic Programming total non uniform patterns idenification

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Can some one give me an idea how to solve following problem

Input:
- Given String of binary numbers "1000101010101"
- pattern "101"
output: an integer indicating possible no of non continuous patterns available

Explanation:

input: "10101"
output: 4

**10**10**1**
**101**01
10**101**
**1**01**01**

Answer (score 3):

Let `s(0), s(1), ...` be the given sequence of binary numbers.

Let `A(n), B(n), C(n)` be the number of appearance of `1`, `10`, `101` in the first `n` terms of `s`, respectively.

Then we have the recurrence relation:

- If `s(n) = 1`, then:

  `A(n) = A(n - 1) + 1`,
  `B(n) = B(n - 1)`,
  `C(n) = C(n - 1) + B(n - 1)`.
- If `s(n) = 0`, then:

  `A(n) = A(n- 1)`,
  `B(n) = B(n - 1) + A(n - 1)`,
  `C(n) = C(n - 1)`.

This immediately gives you an `O(N)` algorithm, which is optimal, since the input is `O(N)`.